# Page table content when the physical page we are looking for is in swap area

Tags: memory, swap, virtual-memory, memory-management

If this question depends on the linux distribution, please answer it in a "general way" (i.e. the most common implementation on linux distributions).

In the page table of a process we can find the physical direction where the page we are looking for is mapped in main memory or a pointer to disk if the page we are looking for isn't present in main memory and we have to catch it from the disk. But my question is: if the page we are looking for is placed in the swap area, what will we find on the page table of that process? We will find a pointer to disk (but pointing to the page in the swap area) or will we find a physical direction but being this physical direction a "virtual direction" which makes  mainMemory + swapArea a unified memory (i.e. if we have 16GB main memory + 2GB swap memory we can see in the page table that the page we are looking for is in the direction X (being X a direction that corresponds to 17GB) and this mean that we will find it in the swap memory (because is >16GB the direction)) ? Remember that we are suposing 16GB main memory + 2GB swap memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page table entry for a page which is swapped out contains bits to indicate that fact (at least one; the details depend on the architecture), and a two-part pointer to the information describing the swapped page. Each swap device or file has a corresponding [`swap_info` structure](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.6/source/mm/swapfile.c#L92), and each of those has a map which links a page table entry to a location in the swap device or file.

See [How does the kernel address swapped memory pages on swap partition\file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/387281/86440) and [the “Swap Management” chapter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand014.html) of Mel Gorman’s *Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager* for details.

Comment: When you say "depend on the architecture" you mean that depends on the exact implementation of the kernel? Or literally on the microprocessor's architecture? And what is a "two-part pointer"?

Comment: I mean it depends on the hardware architecture. The swap pointer is in two parts: the first is an index to find the target swap device or file, the second an offset in the swap map.